# Rhino, using a scriptableObject wrapper to return a Native DateTime

Tags: scala, rhino

I have managed to return a Native DateTime from a scriptable object wrapper, however it involves the wrapper having a reference to the scope and the context.  Is there a better way of doing this, that perhaps does not involve having to pass these references?
(This is implemented in Scala using the JodaTime libraries and Sugar JS)

The test evaluation

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.mozilla.javascript._

object RhinoTest {

  val sugarScript = {
    val c= Context.enter
    val scope = c.initStandardObjects()
    c.compileString(FileUtil.readAllText("sugar-1.3.7.min.js"), "sugar", 1, null)
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    val cx = Context.enter
    val scope = cx.initStandardObjects()
    sugarScript.exec(c1, scope)

    val testDate = new DateTime(2010,10,10, 0, 0)
    val wrapper = Wrapper(Map("date" -> testDate),cx, scope)
    ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "map", wrapper)
    println(c1.evaluateString(scope,"Date.create('Tuesday').isBefore(map.date)", "Source", 1, null))
  }
}
```

and the wrapper class

```
case class Wrapper(map:Map[String,Any], cx:Context, scope:Scriptable) extends ScriptableObject {

  def getClassName() = "Wrapper"

  override def get(name:String, start:Scriptable):Object =
    (map.getOrElse(name, null) match {
      case d:DateTime => {
        val a = List[AnyRef](d.getMillis.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Long]).toArray
        cx.newObject(scope, "Date", a)
      }
      case a => a
    }).asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to convert `Date` to `NativeDate` atomatically. You have to perform the conversion by yourself.

See the answer to a similar question [here](http://dev-tech-js-engine.mozilla.narkive.com/YNCRCrSK/best-way-to-create-native-javascript-date-from-java-with-rhino)

> Rhino does not by default converts Java Number and String objects to
>   corresponding primitive types. Instead it wraps them to a special script
>   objects in the same way as it expose any other JavaObject to scripts via
>   LiveConnect, it only converts primitive Java values to corresponding
>   script values. To override this, you need to provide a custom
>   WrapHandler (WrapFactory in the forthcoming Rhino 1.5R4).
>
> java.util.Date and Date objects in JavaScript are sufficiently different
>   not only by their API, but also by internal presentation. In particular,
>   Date in Script can hold NaN value while java.util.Date can not. For
>   these reasons it is best to left to applications to decide how to
>   convert one to another.

One thing to consider is performing the conversion before the running of the script, avoiding any wrappers:

```
Object nativeDate = cx.newObject(scope, "Date", new Object[] {new Date().getTime()})
ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "date", nativeDate)
```